# Start event when radio button is deselected

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

So, first you selected it and it does the things I told it to do, and then you deselected it, wanting to start an event, but only when it first has been selected.

Comment: Off the top of my head, use a PropertyChangeListener

Comment: Please show what you've attempted and let us know what problems you're having with this attempt. Not your down-voter (yet) by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ItemListener` to the radio button.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an ItemListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) for more information.

> and then you deselected it, wanting to start an event, but only when it first has been selected.

Well, the only way you will get the unselected event is if it has been selected first.